# Разыменование указателя на массив

Tags: c++, массивы, указатели

```
int array[3]{1,2,3};
int (*ptr)[3]=&array;
```

при разыменовании

```
std::cout<<*ptr;
(или std::cout<<ptr[0])
показывает адрес.
```

Тут указатель разыменовывается в массив, который распадается на указатель_на_первый элемент? Типа указатель_на_указателя?

Но это вряд ли, тогда бы `ptr[0]+1` показал адрес следующего элемента.

Или в `std::cout<<ptr[0];` массив распадается, а в `std::cout<<ptr[0]+1;` не распадается?

Comment: *"Тут указатель разыменовывается в массив, который распадается на указатель_на_первый элемент?"* Да, все так. *"ли, тогда бы ptr[0]+1 показал адрес следующего элемента"* А он разве не показывает?

Comment: Указатель на массив и указатель на первый элемент этого массива содержат один и тот же адрес.

Comment: HolyBlackCat , мне сказали, что не показывает, и я написал без проверки. Моя тупость. 
Все показывает. Теперь все стало на места.

Answer (score 6):

В отладчике GDB есть такая комнада как `ptype`, которая показывает тип какого-либо выражения. Она поможет нам разобраться:

```
(gdb) list
1   #include <iostream>
2   
3   int main()
4   {
5       int array[3] = {1, 2, 3};
6       int (*ptr)[3] = &array;
7   
8       std::cout << *ptr;
9   }

(gdb) ptype array
type = int [3]

(gdb) ptype ptr
type = int (*)[3]

(gdb) ptype *ptr
type = int [3]
```

Получается, что в строке

```
std::cout << *ptr;
```

`*ptr` — это сам `array`, который из типа `int [3]` неявно преобразуется<sup>1</sup> в тип `int *`, т. е. в адрес первого элемента массива.

---

<sup>1. Имеет место [array-to-pointer decay](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/array).</sup>

Comment: Вообще-то типом `*ptr` будет `int ( & )[3]`

Comment: @VTT Вроде нет. У выражений ссылочных типов не бывает.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Убедитесь в этом выполнив `static_assert(::std::is_same_v<int ( & )[3], decltype(*ptr)>);`

Comment: @VTT, можете объяснить почему так происходит? Откуда вообще берется ссылка? Где об этом прочитать?

Comment: Формально результатом разыменования указателя на некоторый тип будет объект этого типа. Но не новый, а тот, на который указывает указатель, то бишь ссылка, что отражено в правилах, используемых `decltype`.

Comment: так что    ptrdiff_t dist = *(ptr + 1) - array;   в своем значении будет иметь количество элементов массива

Comment: @VTT Пруф на то, что выражения не бывают ссылками: [`[expr.type]/1`](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr#type-1). На счет `decltype`: если его применить к выражению (не к переменной), он возвращает не только его тип, но и value category. Категория обозначается наличием ссылки в типе: lvalue = `&`, xvalue = `&&`, prvalue = не ссылка. (Т.к. сам тип выражения не может быть ссылкой, конфликтов не возникает.) См. [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype).

Comment: Это можно проверить вот так: `int arr[3]; static_assert(is_same_v<int [3], decltype(arr)>);` (применили к переменной, получили честный тип переменной) `static_assert(is_same_v<int (&)[3], decltype((arr))>);` (применили к выражению, получили тип + value category, запихнутую в ссылку).